# Mac(High Sierra) gcc problem (ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64)

Tags: macos, gcc

I wrote very simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile it, I'v got error:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/user/CLionProjects/NewMath/cmake-build-debug --target NewMath -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable NewMath
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/NewMath.dir/build.make:84: NewMath] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/NewMath.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/NewMath.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:118: NewMath] Ошибка 2
```

I use:
-Clion
-gcc8
-gmake

without Clion error still present

Can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is C++, but `gcc` is a C compiler. Use `g++`, or `g++-7` or `g++-8`:

```
g++-7 main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: Neither g++-7 nor g++-8 work on High-Sierra.  Furthermore, g++ gives me 'Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64' for one module, but none of the others.  Everything compiles and links properly with -m32, but not without it..  This is related to 'full screen'.